# How can I add a custom authoriser to AWS CDK v2 apigatewayv2 Websockets?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-cdk, aws-api-gateway-v2

I have an ApiGateway RestApi with a custom authoriser in AWS CDK v2. Now I want to create a WebSocket with an authoriser.

I started by following this guide [Stack 3: Api Gateway Websocket API AWS CDK Stack Walk-thru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljwZszwxclI&t=4s), which has got me as far as creating the ApiGatewayV2 WebSocket. I'm struggling to figure out how to create a custom authoriser for that.

Some of the questions I have:

- Can I use the same authoriser function with ApiGatewayV2 CfnAuthoriser?
- Does the authorisation need to happen in some kind of websocket style?
- How do I authorise with the WebSocket from the front-end application? Is it just an authentication header like in an HTTP request?

I'm having a hard time googling it, keep getting CDK v1 articles. If anyone has some time to point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

*Main stack*

```
export class ThingCdkStack extends Stack {
    private authoriserLogicalId: string;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps, private envs: Environment) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const api = new RestApi(this, 'ThingApi');

        const role = new Role(this, 'ThingRole', {
            roleName: 'thing-role',
            assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com'),
            inlinePolicies: {
                allowLambdaInvocation: PolicyDocument.fromJson({
                    Version: '2012-10-17',
                    Statement: [
                        {
                            Effect: 'Allow',
                            Action: ['lambda:InvokeFunction', 'lambda:InvokeAsync'],
                            Resource: `arn:aws:lambda:${envs.REGION}:${envs.ACCOUNT}:function:*`,
                        },
                    ],
                }),
            },
        });

        const authorizerHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ThingCustomAuthorizer', {
            entry: 'lambda/handlers/auth/auth0-authoriser.ts',
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            environment: {
                AUTH0_ISSUER: 'https://my-auth.eu.auth0.com/',
                AUTH0_AUDIENCE: 'https://my-demo.com',
                REGION: envs.REGION,
                ACCOUNT: envs.ACCOUNT,
            }
        });

        const authorizer = new CfnAuthorizer(this, 'ThingAuthoriser', {
            restApiId: api.restApiId,
            type: 'TOKEN',
            name: 'thing-authoriser',
            identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
            authorizerUri: `arn:aws:apigateway:${envs.REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${authorizerHandler.functionArn}/invocations`,
            authorizerCredentials: role.roleArn
        });

        this.authoriserLogicalId = authorizer.logicalId;

        const createThingHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'CreateThingLambda', {
            entry: 'lambda/handlers/thing/create-thing.ts',
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
        });

        this.addAuthMethod('post', api.addResource('thing'), createThingHandler);

        this.addWebsocket(envs, authorizer);
    }

    private addAuthMethod(method: string, resource: Resource, handler: NodejsFunction, integrationOptions?: LambdaIntegrationOptions) {
        const route = resource.addMethod(
            method,
            new LambdaIntegration(handler, integrationOptions),
            {
                authorizationType: AuthorizationType.CUSTOM,
            }
        );
        const childResource = route.node.findChild('Resource');

        (childResource as CfnResource).addPropertyOverride('AuthorizationType', AuthorizationType.CUSTOM);
        (childResource as CfnResource).addPropertyOverride('AuthorizerId', {Ref: this.authoriserLogicalId});
    }

    private addWebsocket(environment: Environment, authorizer: CfnAuthorizer) {
        const connectionsTable = new Table(this, 'ConnectionsTable', {
            partitionKey: {name: 'connectionId', type: AttributeType.STRING},
            readCapacity: 2,
            writeCapacity: 1,
            timeToLiveAttribute: "ttl"
        });

        const commonHandlerProps: NodejsFunctionProps = {
            bundling: {minify: true, sourceMap: true, target: 'es2019'},
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            logRetention: RetentionDays.THREE_DAYS
        };

        const connectHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ConnectHandler', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/connect.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const defaultHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'defaultHandler', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/default.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const disconnectHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'DisconnectHandler', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/disconnect.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const websocketApi = new WebsocketApi(this, "CompletionWebsocketApi", {
            apiName: "completions-api",
            apiDescription: "Web Socket API for Completions",
            stageName: environment.STAGE,
            connectHandler,
            disconnectHandler,
            defaultHandler,
            connectionsTable
        });

        const CONNECTION_URL = `https://${websocketApi.api.ref}.execute-api.${Aws.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${environment.STAGE}`;

        const completionHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'CompletionHandler', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/completions.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTION_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName,
                CONNECTION_URL: CONNECTION_URL
            },
        });

        websocketApi.addLambdaIntegration(completionHandler, 'completions', 'CompletionsRoute')

        const managementApiPolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ["execute-api:ManageConnections"],
            resources: [`arn:aws:execute-api:${Aws.REGION}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${websocketApi.api.ref}/*`]
        })
        defaultHandler.addToRolePolicy(managementApiPolicyStatement);
        completionHandler.addToRolePolicy(managementApiPolicyStatement);

        new CfnOutput(this, 'WebsocketConnectionUrl', {value: CONNECTION_URL});

        const websocketApiUrl = `${websocketApi.api.attrApiEndpoint}/${environment.STAGE}`
        new CfnOutput(this, "websocketUrl", {
            value: websocketApiUrl
        });
    }
}
```

*WebsocketApi construct*

```
import { ITable } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
import { IFunction } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { CfnApi, CfnIntegration, CfnRoute, CfnStage, CfnDeployment } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2";
import { ServicePrincipal } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import { Aws, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export interface WebsocketApiProps {
    readonly apiName: string;
    readonly apiDescription: string;
    readonly stageName: string;
    readonly connectHandler: IFunction;
    readonly disconnectHandler: IFunction;
    readonly connectionsTable: ITable;
    readonly defaultHandler?: IFunction;
}

export class WebsocketApi extends Construct {
    readonly props: WebsocketApiProps;
    readonly api: CfnApi;
    readonly deployment: CfnDeployment;

    constructor(parent: Stack, name: string, props: WebsocketApiProps) {
        super(parent, name);
        this.props = props;

        this.api = new CfnApi(this, 'CompletionsWebSocketApi', {
            name: props.apiName,
            description: props.apiDescription,
            protocolType: "WEBSOCKET",
            routeSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action",
        });
        this.deployment = new CfnDeployment(this, "WebsocketDeployment", {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
        });

        new CfnStage(this, "WebsocketStage", {
            stageName: props.stageName,
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            deploymentId: this.deployment.ref,
        });

        props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.connectHandler);
        props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.disconnectHandler);

        this.addLambdaIntegration(props.connectHandler, "$connect", "ConnectionRoute");
        this.addLambdaIntegration(props.disconnectHandler, "$disconnect", "DisconnectRoute");

        if(props.defaultHandler) {
            props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.defaultHandler);
            this.addLambdaIntegration(props.defaultHandler, "$default", "DefaultRoute");
        }
    }

    addLambdaIntegration(handler: IFunction, routeKey: string, operationName: string, apiKeyRequired?: boolean, authorizationType?: string) {
        const integration = new CfnIntegration(this, `${operationName}Integration`, {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            integrationType: "AWS_PROXY",
            integrationUri: `arn:aws:apigateway:${Aws.REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${handler.functionArn}/invocations`
        });

        handler.grantInvoke(new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com', {
            conditions: {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": `arn:aws:execute-api:${Aws.REGION}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${this.api.ref}/*/*`
                }
            }
        }));

        this.deployment.addDependency(new CfnRoute(this, `${operationName}Route`, {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            routeKey,
            apiKeyRequired,
            authorizationType: authorizationType || "NONE",
            operationName,
            target: `integrations/${integration.ref}`
        }));
    }
}
```

A full working stack of what I have so far can be found here: https://github.com/OrderAndCh4oS/aws-cdk-v2-apigatewayv2-websocket-demo

**Update**
I've found some useful documentation that I'm working now through:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-lambda-auth.html

Have also found a sample project using Cognito: https://github.com/aws-samples/websocket-api-cognito-auth-sample

Comment: This https://dev.to/rahulmlokurte/how-to-validate-requests-to-the-aws-api-gateway-using-cdk-291c ,can do validation.You thought of adding JWT?

Comment: @RichardRublev Yeah, it's the authorisation that I'm after. The custom authoriser handles JWT auth. I have that working with the RestApi, but the WebSockets use CloudFormation templates, and I'm a little lost.

Comment: There is an example in https://github.com/aws-samples/websocket-api-cognito-auth-sample/blob/main/cdk/lib/construct/websocket.ts

Answer (score 0):

Have made some progress, it's still rough around the edges but is working at least.

I created an ApiGatewayV2 CfnAuthoriser and hooked that up with the `deployment.addDependency()` on the $connect route, and set the `authorizationType` to `CUSTOM`.

The handler is just a regular custom authoriser lambda, but I had to use a querystring parameter to pass the token in.

An authorisation token is passed in on the query string when calling the WebSocket `` const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev?auth=${token} ``);
`

**Main Stack**

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import {Aws, CfnOutput} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import {Construct} from 'constructs';
import {AttributeType, Table} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
import {WebsocketApi} from "./websocket-api";
import {RetentionDays} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-logs";
import {NodejsFunction, NodejsFunctionProps} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs";
import {Effect, PolicyStatement} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import {Environment} from "../bin/environment";
import {Runtime} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";

export class AwsCdkV2WebsocketStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps, private envs: Environment) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        this.addWebsocket(envs);
    }

    private addWebsocket(envs: Environment) {
        const connectionsTable = new Table(this, 'ConnectionsTableWebsocketDemo', {
            partitionKey: {name: 'connectionId', type: AttributeType.STRING},
            readCapacity: 2,
            writeCapacity: 1,
            timeToLiveAttribute: "ttl"
        });

        const commonHandlerProps: NodejsFunctionProps = {
            bundling: {minify: true, sourceMap: true, target: 'es2019'},
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            logRetention: RetentionDays.THREE_DAYS
        };

        const connectHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'ConnectHandlerWebsocketDemo', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/connect.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const authorizationHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'AuthorisationHandlerWebsocketDemo', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/handlers/authorisation.ts',
            environment: {
                // Todo: use env
                ISSUER: 'https://app-auth.eu.auth0.com/',
                AUDIENCE: 'https://app-demo.com',
            }
        });

        const defaultHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'DefaultHandlerWebsocketDemo', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/default.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const disconnectHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'DisconnectHandlerWebsocketDemo', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/disconnect.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTIONS_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName
            }
        });

        const websocketApi = new WebsocketApi(
            this,
            "MessageWebsocketApiWebsocketDemo",
            {
                apiName: "messages-api",
                apiDescription: "Web Socket API for Completions",
                stageName: envs.STAGE,
                connectHandler,
                disconnectHandler,
                defaultHandler,
                connectionsTable,
                authorizationHandler
            },
            envs
        );

        const CONNECTION_URL = `https://${websocketApi.api.ref}.execute-api.${Aws.REGION}.amazonaws.com/${envs.STAGE}`;

        const messageHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'CompletionHandlerWebsocketDemo', {
            ...commonHandlerProps,
            entry: 'lambda/websocket/message.ts',
            environment: {
                CONNECTION_TBL: connectionsTable.tableName,
                CONNECTION_URL
            },
        });

        websocketApi.addLambdaIntegration(messageHandler, 'message', 'CompletionsRoute')

        const managementApiPolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            actions: ["execute-api:ManageConnections"],
            resources: [`arn:aws:execute-api:${Aws.REGION}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${websocketApi.api.ref}/*`]
        })
        defaultHandler.addToRolePolicy(managementApiPolicyStatement);
        messageHandler.addToRolePolicy(managementApiPolicyStatement);

        new CfnOutput(this, 'WebsocketConnectionUrl', {value: CONNECTION_URL});

        const websocketApiUrl = `${websocketApi.api.attrApiEndpoint}/${envs.STAGE}`
        new CfnOutput(this, "WebsocketUrl", {
            value: websocketApiUrl
        });
    }
}
```

**WebSocket API Stack**

```
import { ITable } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
import { IFunction } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import {CfnApi, CfnIntegration, CfnRoute, CfnStage, CfnDeployment, CfnAuthorizer} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2";
import {PolicyDocument, Role, ServicePrincipal} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import { Aws, Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import {Environment} from "../bin/environment";

export interface WebsocketApiProps {
    readonly apiName: string;
    readonly apiDescription: string;
    readonly stageName: string;
    readonly connectHandler: IFunction;
    readonly disconnectHandler: IFunction;
    readonly connectionsTable: ITable;
    readonly authorizationHandler: IFunction;
    readonly defaultHandler?: IFunction;
}

export class WebsocketApi extends Construct {
    readonly props: WebsocketApiProps;
    readonly api: CfnApi;
    readonly deployment: CfnDeployment;

    constructor(parent: Stack, name: string, props: WebsocketApiProps, envs: Environment) {
        super(parent, name);
        this.props = props;

        this.api = new CfnApi(this, 'CompletionsWebSocketApi', {
            name: props.apiName,
            description: props.apiDescription,
            protocolType: "WEBSOCKET",
            routeSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
        });

        this.deployment = new CfnDeployment(this, "WebsocketDeployment", {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
        });

        new CfnStage(this, "WebsocketStage", {
            stageName: props.stageName,
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            deploymentId: this.deployment.ref,
        });

        const role = new Role(this, 'AuthorisedRole', {
            roleName: 'authorised-role',
            assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com'),
            inlinePolicies: {
                allowLambdaInvocation: PolicyDocument.fromJson({
                    Version: '2012-10-17',
                    Statement: [
                        {
                            Effect: 'Allow',
                            Action: ['lambda:InvokeFunction', 'lambda:InvokeAsync'],
                            Resource: `arn:aws:lambda:${envs.REGION}:${envs.ACCOUNT}:function:*`,
                        },
                    ],
                }),
            },
        });

        const authorizer = new CfnAuthorizer(this, 'WorkspaceAuthoriser', {
            name: 'workspace-authoriser',
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            authorizerType: 'REQUEST',
            identitySource: ['route.request.querystring.auth'],
            authorizerUri: `arn:aws:apigateway:${envs.REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${this.props.authorizationHandler.functionArn}/invocations`,
            authorizerCredentialsArn: role.roleArn,
        });
        this.addLambdaIntegration(props.connectHandler, "$connect", "ConnectionRoute", false,"CUSTOM",  authorizer);

        props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.connectHandler);
        props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.disconnectHandler);

        this.addLambdaIntegration(props.disconnectHandler, "$disconnect", "DisconnectRoute");

        if(props.defaultHandler) {
            props.connectionsTable.grantWriteData(props.defaultHandler);
            this.addLambdaIntegration(props.defaultHandler, "$default", "DefaultRoute");
        }
    }

    addLambdaIntegration(handler: IFunction, routeKey: string, operationName: string, apiKeyRequired?: boolean, authorizationType?: string, authorizer?: CfnAuthorizer) {
        const integration = new CfnIntegration(this, `${operationName}Integration`, {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            integrationType: "AWS_PROXY",
            integrationUri: `arn:aws:apigateway:${Aws.REGION}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${handler.functionArn}/invocations`,
        });

        handler.grantInvoke(new ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com', {
            conditions: {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": `arn:aws:execute-api:${Aws.REGION}:${Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}:${this.api.ref}/*/*`
                }
            }
        }));

        this.deployment.addDependency(new CfnRoute(this, `${operationName}RouteWebsocketDemo`, {
            apiId: this.api.ref,
            routeKey,
            apiKeyRequired,
            authorizationType: authorizationType || "NONE",
            operationName,
            target: `integrations/${integration.ref}`,
            authorizerId: authorizer?.attrAuthorizerId,
        }));
    }
}
```

**Authorisation Handler**

```
if (!process.env.AUDIENCE) throw new Error('Missing AUDIENCE');
if (!process.env.ISSUER) throw new Error('Missing ISSUER');
if (!process.env.AWS_REGION) throw new Error('Missing AWS_REGION');

const JWKS_URI = `${process.env.ISSUER}.well-known/jwks.json`

export const handler = async (event: any, context: any, callback: any) => {
    let data;
    try {
        data = await authenticate(event);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('UNAUTHORISED', err);
        return context.fail('Unauthorized');
    }

    console.log('AUTHORISED', data);
    return data;
};

const getPolicyDocument = (effect: any, resource: any) => {
    return {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [{
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: effect,
            Resource: resource,
        }]
    };
}

const getToken = (event: any) => {
    if (!event.type || event.type !== 'REQUEST') {
        throw new Error('Expected "event.type" parameter to have value "REQUEST"');
    }

    const tokenString = event.queryStringParameters?.auth;
    if (!tokenString) {
        throw new Error('Expected "event.queryStringParameters.auth" parameter to be set');
    }

    return tokenString;
}

const jwtOptions = {
    audience: process.env.AUDIENCE,
    issuer: process.env.ISSUER
};

const client = jwksClient({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10,
    jwksUri: JWKS_URI
});

const authenticate = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
    const token = getToken(event);

    const decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
    if (!decoded || !decoded.header || !decoded.header.kid) {
        throw new Error('invalid token');
    }

    const getSigningKey = util.promisify(client.getSigningKey);
    return getSigningKey(decoded.header.kid)
        .then((key: any) => {
            const signingKey = key?.publicKey || key?.rsaPublicKey;
            return jwt.verify(token, signingKey, jwtOptions);
        })
        .then((decoded: any) => ({
            principalId: decoded.sub,
            policyDocument: getPolicyDocument('Allow', '*'),
            context: {scope: decoded.scope}
        }));
}
```

I made a scratch demo project for this which may or may not be useful to someone: https://github.com/OrderAndCh4oS/aws-cdk-v2-apigatewayv2-websocket-demo

Will leave the question open in case someone is able to improve on this, it certainly needs work still.